# show value in a UITextField in another viewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uitextfield, segue

Hi

I have StarViewController, where the user enters data ( height, weight ) in different UITextFields

There is a button called calculate when the user clicks on calculate 
I want the button a segue to resultViewController

and resultViewController I have 3  UITextField

maxima,     minim,       actual,

these values ​​in this 3 UITextField

in maxima value maxima
in minim valeu minim
in actual  the same value that user enter

I only need the code for the button that performs this action and the code to Show these values ​​in resultViewController

This is my code:

```
-(void)heightMethod{
  double cm = _maxima.text.doubleValue;
  if(cm >=1.50 && cm <=1.55)  {
    _maxima.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"61"];
    _minim.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"45"];
}else if(cm >=1.60 && cm<=1.65){
    _maxima.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"71"];
    _minim.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"49"];
}else if (cm >= 1.70 && cm <=1.75){
    _maxima.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"82"];
    _minim.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"53"];
}else if (cm >=1.80 && cm <=1.85){
    _maxima.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"87"];
    _minim.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"60"];
}else if (cm >=1.90 && cm >= 1.95){
    _maxima.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"92"];
    _minim.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"63"];
}else if (cm >=2.00){
    _maxima.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"100"];
    _minim.text = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"71"];
}


}

-(void)actualWeightMethod{
double kgActual = _aktual.text.doubleValue;
if (kgActual  >=50 && kgActual <= 55) {
    _aktual.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"equal aktual"];
}else if (kgActual >=60 &&  kgActual<= 65){
    _aktual.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"equal aktual"];
}else if (kgActual >=70 &&kgActual <=75){
    _aktual.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"equal aktual"];
}else if (kgActual  >=80 && kgActual <=85){
    _aktual.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"equal aktual"];
}else if (kgActual  >=90 && kgActual <=95){
    _aktual.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"equal aktual"];
}else if (kgActual  >=100){
    _aktual.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"equal aktual"];
}


}
- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender{

   ResultViewController *destViewController = (ResultViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
   //Create 3 NSStrings in your resultViewController and set your values desired for show them as you want.
   destViewController.max = yourValueMax;
   destViewController.min = yourValueMin;
   destViewController.actual = yourValueActual;

}
```